# Button text floats outside of button

Tags: css

I have a few buttons where the text is half in and half out of the button. It's not extending over the right side of the button because it is too long. It is just cut in half by the bottom horizontal border of the button.

Being new to this I am just throwing the kitchen sink at the button css without really knowing what it will do. Any help appreciated.

```
color:yellow;
background-color:aquamarine;
height: 20px;
width: 100px;
border:none 0px transparent;
font-size: 1px;
float:right;
overflow:visible;
vertical-align:text-top;
text-align:center;
padding-top:65px;
text-overflow: ellipsis;
```

Comment: Have you tried removing the height and width css property you set? You don't necessarily need to do that. Let the text determine the width of the button

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I removed them and now the text is inside the button but the button is too big now. I tried making the text smaller too but even if I make the text XX small tit sits right at the bottom of the button. I cant seem to centre it vertically.

Comment: Your padding-top is likely responsible for that. Padding-top adds to the default height of the button

Comment: Sadly, I only added that padding whilst trying to fix this problem. I have removed it but nothing has changed.

Answer (score 1):

```
color:yellow;
background-color:aquamarine;
border:none 0px transparent;
font-size: 1px;
float:right;
overflow:visible;
vertical-align:text-top;
text-align:center;
padding-top:65px;
text-overflow: ellipsis;
```

No need for specifying width or height as it will cut the text

Answer (score 0):

```
<body>
  <button id="btn">
    THIS IS A TEXT
  </button>
</body>
```

For the css use this

```
#btn {
  color:black;
  background-color:aquamarine;
  /*height: 20px;
  width: 100px;*/
  border:none 0px transparent;
  /*font-size: 1px;*/
  float:right;
  overflow:visible;
  vertical-align:text-top;
  text-align:center;
  padding: 10px;
  /*padding-top:65px;*/
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

You can just use `padding` property alone, that adds to the four directions of the text. The `font-size` was too small.

Check it out [here](https://jsfiddle.net/1wqw358g/1/).

Comment: Thanks. But if I don't include the height and width limits the button becomes too big.

Comment: Thanks. I sorted it by not using the height and width but the padding. Thanks for your help.